# How to route many paths to one url in django python

Tags: python-3.x, django

I would like to route all paths ending in 'search/' to one url. I have tried many ways, But nothing worked.

the following is the last that I tried.

```
path(r'^search/$', views.search, name="search"),
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

After writing this, it occurs to me that you are using `path` which does not process regular expressions. You should probably be using `url` (deprecated) or `re_path`. If that's not it, ...

`urls.py` in an app is included into the master project `urls.py`. This results in a heirarchical structure. for example. most Django sites have a project `urls.py` containing

```
 url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

which dispatches any URL starting `/admin` to the Django admin code. that code dispatches based on the remaining part of the URL. That code's `urls.py` never sees `/admin`.

If you really want to catch anything starting `/search` rather than only `/myapp/search` you'll have to put the path or url definition in the top-level (project) `urls.py`. Unusual, but perfectly possible

```
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
path(r'search/$', search_app.views.search, name="search"),
```

I have no idea what the namespace will be (for `reverse("dont_know:search")` )

Comment: Thanks for your response @nigel222. I have tried what you suggested, but it did not work.

Comment: Just added  `url(r'^foobar/', NotImplementedView.as_view() ),` after admin in my dev project. It worked. (NotImplementedView is a TemplateView/ placeholder of mine that displays "Not Implemented yet")

Comment: The following is what I added to url.py from the main project after admin ```url(r'^search/$', login.search, name="search"),```  and this is the path error ```The current path, projects_list/search/, didn’t match any of these.``` Thanks @nigel222